# I have trouble with OnResume method

Tags: android, sensors

I am doing a app that implement SensorEventListener but I have a problem with onResume method
The logcat tell me that there is a nullpointerexception but I dont understand why
This is my activity

```
public class T11Ej2 extends Activity {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
private SampleView mView;
private float[] mValues;


private final SensorEventListener mListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mValues = event.values;
        if(mView != null){
            mView.invalidate();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);            
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mView = new SampleView(this);
    setContentView(mView);
}






@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mListener);

}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mListener, 
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.t11_ej2, menu);
    return true;
}

// Código para pintar la brujula
private class SampleView extends View{

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private Path mPath = new Path();

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mPath.moveTo(0, -50);
        mPath.lineTo(-20, 60);
        mPath.lineTo(0, 50);
        mPath.lineTo(20, 60);
        mPath.close();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Paint paint = mPaint;
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            int w = canvas.getWidth();
            int h = canvas.getHeight();
            int cx = w / 2;
            int cy = h / 2;
            canvas.translate(cx, cy);

            if (mValues != null) {
            canvas.rotate(-mValues[0]);
            }
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }   
}}
```

This is logcat

```
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.t11ej2/com.example.t11ej2.T11Ej2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-29 01:51:27.758: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `mSensorManager` is `null` because you haven't initialized it before trying to use it in `onResume()`. `onResume()` is called right after `onCreate()` so you will need to initialize this before `onResume()` is called.

I haven't used this so I'm definitely not an expert but in [the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) this is how they initialize it

```
  public SensorActivity() {
     mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
     mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
 }

 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you initialized mListener, its callback functions, onSensorChanged and onAccuracyChanged, actually have not been called until the listener registered. That means the mSensorManager is still null. Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,the method registerListener and unregisterListener are incorrectness. you need see Activity lifecycle!so, you should change method onResume() to onStart().
Second,this method:

```
public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mPath.moveTo(0, -50);
        mPath.lineTo(-20, 60);
        mPath.lineTo(0, 50);
        mPath.lineTo(20, 60);
        mPath.close();
    }
```

, I think you should do this in onDraw method ,you should't close mPath until draw complete.
good luck.